# What is an Anonymous Object?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, standards

What is an Anonymous Object exactly?

Does C++ support/have Anonymous Objects?

Comment: The are things called *anonymous structs* and *anonymous unions*, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: No i meant Anonymous Objects.

Comment: Define "Anonymous Object" (and note that while no "anonymous objects" are defined in C++ standardese, the words *unnamed* and *anonymous* are both used and mean specific and slightly different things. cf. "Anonymous union defines an unnamed object of unnamed type").

Comment: @Cubbi: That's the question.

Comment: An anonymous class instance could be useful.  Eg: a class that records the time when it is instantiated, and prints a message and the delta time when it goes out of scope.  There's no need for the instance to have a name.  Instead of `Timer xTimer("My Timer Message");` it would be nice to just do `Timer("My Timer Message");`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The C++ standard does not define the term "anonymous object", but it stands to reason that one might sanely use the term to describe any object that has no name:

- Temporaries: `f(T());`
- Unnamed function parameters: `void func(int, int, int);`

What I *wouldn't* count is dynamically-allocated objects:

Technically speaking, an "object" is any region of storage [1.8/1 in 2003], which would include the X bytes making up the integer dynamically-allocated by `new int;`.

In `int* ptr = new int;` the pointer (itself an object too, don't forget!) has the name `ptr` and the integer itself has no name other than `*ptr`. Still, I'd hesitate to call this an anonymous object.

Again, though, there's no standard terminology.

Comment: there is no definition of "anonymous object", although the spec uses the term "unnamed object" (in that meaning, i.e "object without a name"), which seems like a similar term.

Answer (score 2):

Note that anonymous object and anonymous class/type are different concepts.
This post explains the latter.

---

This is a simplistic answer, but an anonymous object is basically an object which the compiler creates a `class` for.

For example in C# (I know this is kinda irrelevant) you can just create an anonymous type by doing:

`new { filename = value }`.

The compiler effectively creates a class called `AnonSomething1` [A random name you don't know] which has those fields.  Therefore at that point you just created an instance of that `AnonSomething1`.  C++ does not allow you to make anonymous class types inline (like Java and C# which have a base Object class which the anon types can derive).

However you can make an anonymous struct by simply writing

```
struct { 
    int field1; 
    std::string field2; 
} myanonstruct;
```

which creates an anonymous struct and instantiates it with the alias `myanonstruct`. This C++ code does not define a type, it just creates an anonymous one with 1 instance.

See C#: [Anon Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)

See Java: [Anon Types](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm)

See C++ Structs: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64973255%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: anonymous object != anonymous class

Comment: What Andrey said. I'd downvote, but I hit my votecap for the day.

Comment: I assumed he was talking about anonymous types because C++ could not exist without anonymous objects, there would be no way to copy args, return by value, operator overload, etc. without anon objects.