# In Line Instantiation of Objects

Tags: java, inline-code

This is a very general question and i'd like to apologize in advance for the noob question BUT....

in java, well in general, is there a specific name for in line declarations, or is it simply called just that?

i'm referring to the method below for declaring objects:

`panel.add(new JLabel("Hello World"));`

as opposed to:

`JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World);
panel.add(label);`

Comment: That's not a declaration, that's an instantiation (statement or expression, I forget which).

Comment: I don't think there's a special name for that. Is only Java Syntax

Comment: thanks everyone for your answers! appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People seem to call it "anonymous object" or "unnamed object". See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/5330408/659002

Comment: names, names and some more syntax! =]
thanks everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a specific name for this.

You're not "declaring" the label, though. You're just "instantiating" an instance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is, inline-script or running code is all i've heard it called, sometimes single line delimited.

```
JLabel labe;
panel.add(labe = new JLabel("Hello World"));


//Instantiation
JLabel label = **new** JLabel("Hello World);

//declaration
JLabel label,label2,label3;
```

Answer (score 1):

The Java Language Specification calls

```
new JLabel("Hello World")
```

an [instance creation expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9), and

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World);
```

a [variable declaration with a variable initializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4) (where the initializer happens to contain an instance creation expression).

That is, the JLS says *variables* are *declared*, and *objects created*. These are independent concepts; you can declare variables without creating objects, and create objects without declaring variables.

To emphasize the difference between the code examples you could say that you do (or don't) declare a variable, as in "there is no need to declare a variable here" or "putting the reference into a variable helps with debugging".