# Creating a class object without a variable

Tags: class, oop, object, c++14

So I create my class Cars. Then I make a variable(audi) for an object from my class cars. Everything is fine and dandy but I noticed that I can create an object(with an engine value of 50) without specifying a variable for it to be held in. So now how can I access that object?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Cars
{
public:
    int getStatus();
    Cars(int engine=5);
private:
    int m_engine;
};
Cars::Cars(int engine)
{
    m_engine=engine;
    cout<<"A new car is made."<<endl;
}
Cars::getStatus()
{
    cout<<m_engine<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    Cars audi(10);
    audi.getStatus();
    Cars(50);

}
```

Comment: `Cars(50).getStatus();` for instance.

Comment: I tried that and it activates the constructor so does it recreate it?

Comment: You're creating an object, so of course it uses the constructor. I'm not sure what you were expecting or what you mean by *recreate*.

Comment: Well what I meant was that it should have already been created. I use Cars(50) once and then on the next line Cars(50).getStatus() and both times I get "A new car is made".

Comment: Right, so you've used Cars(50) twice so two objects have been created. If you want to create an object **and have it stick around** then you're going to need a variable. These objects created without variables are called temporaries because they don't stick around for long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on when you want to access the object.

```
Cars(50);
```

With this piece of code, you create a temporary object that lives only during execution of the current statement (i. e. until execution of your code passes the semicolon).

```
Cars(50);
// I want to access the object here
```

In this case: Too late. The temporary has already been destroyed and doesn't exist any more. No chance to get back to it. You can, however, use the object as long as it lives, e. g. call a member function on it or pass it to another function:

```
Cars(10).doSomething();
// but right now (after the semicolon), the car doesn't exist any more
doSomethingElse(Cars(12));
// again, the object got destroyed
```

Be aware that in above example, you created two *distinct* instances, each ceasing to exist when reaching the semicolon. Be aware, too, that the objects' destructors get called at this point of time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it all together, like this:

```
Cars(50).getStatus();
```

Otherwise you won't have a way to refer to your car with 50 m_engine.

This temporary should be used with fidelity. Read more in [What is an Anonymous Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330287/what-is-an-anonymous-object)

Answer (score 0):

You can't! It's already dead by the time you try. `Cars(50)` is a temporary, and its lifetime ends at the end of its full-expression -- that is, at the `;`.

Comment: So what's wrong with `Cars(50).getStatus();`? or `some_function(Cars(50));`?

Comment: @john I assumed that by "now" OP meant "after that line, unmodified" (i.e. where there's a blank line in the question). I gather from your comment's upvotes that I am the dumb one here.

Comment: Well you might be right, wouldn't be the first newbie to ask a question in an unclear way.