# Can you access anonymous objects/types in C++?

Tags: c++, reference, anonymous-types

I'm currently learning about references in C++. Here's something I've been wondering about:

```
int x = 5;
const int &ref = 3 * x + 1;
```

My understanding of this is that an *anonymous variable* is created for this expression `3 * x + 1` to be stored in it. After that, we tie our reference `ref` to that anonymous variable. That way we can access it although we can't change the value because its type is `const`.

**Question:** Is there a way we can access this anonymous variable/object apart from using the reference `ref`? In general, does C++ allow access to these anonymous objects?

Comment: It’s not anonymous, it’s a temporary.

Comment: Being *temporary* doesn't preclude being *anonymous*. What is it called?

Comment: ... and correct terminology is very important in C++. You may think that it's accurate to describe something like this as "anonymous", but in C++ there is a specific term for this: temporary lifetime extension. Something else ***entirely*** in C++ is described as "anonymous" - namespaces. There will be endless confusion if the wrong terms are used to describe specific concepts.

Comment: No, there's no other way. Note that that temporary object is not a variable, the only variables here are `x` and `ref` (a variable must be introduced by a declaration). Also I'm unsure if the temporary is `const` or not (if not, you could `const_cast` the reference to modify it; otherwise that would be UB).

Comment: Related/dupe: [What is an Anonymous Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5330287/10871073)

Comment: @AdrianMole it’s called “ref”.

Comment: @Taekahn Heh - fair enough. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I think it should be of `const` type, so modification through `const_cast` is not allowed. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2481.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a *temporary object* (it is not a variable). And it doesn't store the *expression*, but the *result* of the expression.

Normally such objects are destroyed at the end of the full expression in which they are created. However if a reference is bound to them *immediately*, then these objects will live as long as that reference (with some exceptions not applying here).

So yes, you can use `ref` here exactly in the same way as if you had written

```
const int ref = 3 * x + 1;
```

instead. (With some minor exceptions like `decltype(ref)` being different.)

There is no other way to access such objects other than binding a reference to them. But that isn't really a restriction. You can do (almost) everything you can do with the name of a variable also with a reference to a variable/object.

Comment: Thanks for this, I get it now. By storing the expression I meant the results, but that's bad wording on my part, so thank you for clearing that up as well.

Comment: @nocomment • as `x` changes later, it won't change the value that `ref` holds.  (This is sometimes a point of confusion for people first learning C++.)

Answer (score -2):

Let's start first with the terminology: what you called "anonymous" is actually called "temporary" in the C++ language. Temporary variables/objects/instances are those that are implicitly declared as part of a C++ expression, but are not explicitly assigned to a variable.

For example, in your code snippet "3 * x" would be a temporary value. Temporary expressions are managed by the compiler, so there is no no way for you to access them from regular C++ code. If you need to do so, just declare a variable with the temporary result that you need and use it.

Being said that, I believe that you may be missing how references "&" work in C++. When you declare a type with the reference sign at the end (such as your "const int & ref") you are telling the compiler that "ref" is an alias of what is being assigned to ref, in this case, an alias of "3 * x + 1". Your code snippet works because you are declaring that reference as "const", thus the compiler can treat the "const int&" as a regular "const int" and use the computed value wherever it is needed.

However, if you remove the "const" you will see that you code cannot be compiled. That happens because without the "const", you are declaring a regular reference, which by definition can be changed. However, since you are assigning to it the result of a temporary expression (which of course cannot be changed because it is temporary) and it has no predetermined storage, the compiler is finding a wrong usage of a reference.

Comment: [Skitt's law](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Skitts%20Law) in action right there. :P There are no temporary variables/values/expressions/instances (I don't think the latter is a valid term), only objects. Objects that are not variables are not "declared". `const int &ref` is not a "type declaration".

Comment: As @HolyBlackCat mentioned the terminology you are using isn't correct either. Even if I try to interpret it the answer is incorrect: Because `x` has type `int`, `3 * x` does not actually create a temporary object. A temporary object is created in OP's code only from the prvalue expression `3 * x + 1` because a reference is bound to it. The fact that the reference is `const` is also irrelevant. Had OP used `int&&` instead of `const int&` they would have a reference to the temporary object which they are allowed to modify.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I was reviewing now the C++ standard and yes, my terminology was wrong too, the standard always talks about "objects". And it is also true that the expression is a prvalue, so there is no temporary involved. Should I remove my answer to avoid confusing other people, fix it, or just leave it as it is now? I am pretty new in stackoverflow.